# iPhone: Animate the Market statistics Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

We have an iTrading iPhone app where we allow people to trade on different commodities. For now we have market view controller where we display user's preferred market statistics in UITableView. We are looking for adding single stripe line at the bottom of iPhone App which always has market statistics running. This kind of view is available on most of news site where they display XXX company is up, YYY company is down etc with their current share price. These all companies information continuously keep moving Left->Right till end and start again from start so it's rotate basically. You can assume that I have a market statistics array which continuously updated using Socket connection from server.

Could anyone please tell me how could I implement this functionality on iPhone. I don't understand what Animation should I use for this. Also I want to allow user to move this statistics quickly in either side(L->R or R->L) using gesture recognizer! I am sure this is very common functionality so just wondering is any library available for this.

Thanks.

Comment: this might help : https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen an app developed my company which uses core-plot for this feature. You should dig into it.